# I'm giving a talk on askubuntu.com; show me your favorite things!

Tags: discussion

I am fortunate to be giving a talk at the Ubucon as part of the [Ohio LinuxFest](http://www.ohiolinux.org/) tomorrow about Ask Ubuntu.

I'm preparing my slides and I have a set of images that I use to convey what AU is about. Things like "Community Editing is amazing" and then I show an example like this:

[image]

I'd like to include things that the community feel the site does awesome (or not awesome!), so I was wondering if you could post a screenshot or link of your favorite edit, your favorite answer or question of all time, your funniest review/edit ever, things of that sort. I am aware of https://askubuntu.com/questions/greatest-hits already, but I think we all have a favorite (or hated) thing about the site that you'd like to point out!

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies, but what I like about AU is that I get to learn so many new things about Ubuntu. The website itself is nice, but not flawless. The **content** is what makes me want to come back. That content is undeniable related to the **community**.

Comment: So, is there anyway we can see your talk now that it's finished?

Comment: @Seth Marco gave this talk at SCALE last month, I'll see if the video is up yet.

Comment: No luck I take it @JorgeCastro? I tried looking it up myself, but it seems SCALE's website wasn't working well in the streaming category.

Comment: @Seth I know there's a video somewhere, I'll ask around

Comment: Wow, been a while. Any chance you know if/where this talk is? I'd still like to watch it!

Answer (score 15):

We like to keep things helpful and clean, though that doesn't mean we don't have a sense of humour.

[image]

(no offence to gentoo users)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install coffee-to-keyboard`. Nice one!

Comment: Somehow this reminded me of http://xkcd.com/797/...

Answer (score 10):

I'm bored, so here's what I got:

- At Ask Ubuntu, we [help new users](https://askubuntu.com/q/344747/52726) in understanding how the site works:

  [image]
- At Ask Ubuntu, we try to [avoid broken links](https://askubuntu.com/a/334850/52726) in answers:

  [image]
- At Ask Ubuntu, we ask that [people post informative answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/337296/52726):

  [image]
- At Ask Ubuntu, we have a sense of humor!

  [image]

Okay that last one is not from Ask Ubuntu, but it's still hilarious =).

Comment: hahaha that last one

Comment: These are all excellent, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro hey is this talk streamed somewhere? Or can I watch it somewhere after it's over? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

We are excellent at solving marital problems.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

How about starting at the top?

> ## A well asked question is easy to find…

[image]

> ## The best answers rise to the top

[image]

> ## …while less useful answers… ***don't.***

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What I like about Ask Ubuntu is the way that It's built and run by the users. This means that the site is for users by users. When you are thinking of a feature request its most likely that someone shares the same view. Also the dedicated guys who toil everyday in the close votes queue making sure substandard questions and spam don't make it onto the site.

When I first switched (partially) to Ubuntu I visited the forums and I did not like it. Don't get me wrong, Ubuntu Forums are an integral part of the Ubuntu Community but, its not just my thing. I was having a problem with wireless on Natty and I had looked through many solutions but couldn't solve the problem.

By chance or good luck I ended up on AU, to cut a long story short I found an answer that solved my problem (something about ndiswrapper) of course I cannot remember the solution now :) but I've never left AU since although I have been a passive user. I love that people are willing to help and they try as much as they can not to be rude and maintain patience.

Also I like that your experience is not judged by your age (lots of teens here know so much it surprises me). Lastly and according to me the best reason for AU's existence is the feeling of community, the feeling you get when your answer is picked as the answer by the OP and the feeling that you are helping the community especially when they comment "thanks" (though highly frowned upon) and give upvotes.